# Apps Script в код подставить ID и имя листа из ячеек рабочего листа

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Можно ли заменить жесткую привязку в коде NameDoc NameListDoc на ячейку из листа, периодически будет меняться как id документа, так и название листа, но не хочется залазить в код.
На "Лист1" сейчас указано в ячейке А1 - id документа ...., в ячейке А2 - название листа 01_24.
Текущий код:

```
function distrib() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var NameList = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Лист1");
  var NameDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1iGfG3xSrkQ_7J3XU38LENpzwRprjTomAYLLQw89Gkr8');
  var NameListDoc = destinationSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("01_24");

  var f = NameList.getRange('C4').getValues() ; if (f != ''){NameListDoc.getRange('B5').setValues(f);}
  var f = NameList.getRange('C5').getValues() ; if (f != ''){NameListDoc.getRange('B6').setValues(f);}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то у вас есть таблица, предположим с листом `Лист1`, на котором в ячейках `A1:A2` вы периодически меняете ID и имя листа внешней таблицы, с которой нужно проводить какие-то манипуляции. Тогда вы получаете значения из `A1:A2`

```
var getIDandName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Лист1").getRange('A1:A2').getValues();
```

а дальше подставляете их в свою формулу. Например, если вы хотите получить данные с ячейки `F1` таблицы, чьи ID и Имя листа берутся из ячеек `A1:A2`, то выглядит это так:

```
var NameListDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getIDandName[0][0]).getSheetByName(getIDandName[1][0]).getRange('F1').getValue();
```